# What could be overriding the return code from main()?

Tags: c++, exception, return-value, program-entry-point

I have a rather odd occurrence happening that I haven't been able to nut out yet.

I have test case that is supposed to catch errors and return the appropriate error code from main, but /sometimes/ on test runs the program returns 0 even when the error code is non zero.

The exception class thrown is:

```
class exit_request {
public:
    explicit exit_request(int code = 0) : m_code(code) {}
    int code() const { return m_code; }
private:
    int m_code;
};
```

The test case code is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try {
        // Do some test case stuff
        // Eventually, due to the supplied command line arguments,
        // we expect an exit_request() to be thrown from within
        // library code.       
    }
    catch (exit_request& exp) {
        std::cout << "Exit Request:" << exp.code() << std::endl;
        return exp.code();
    }
    catch (std::exception& err) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << err.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In many runs of this test case, everything works as expected: The exit_request() exception is thrown, caught, exp.code() is printed (its value is 2), and the return code from the process is 2.

However, very occasionally, the return code from the process is 0 (i.e. no failure), even though exp.code() is printed as 2.

Can anyone help explain a situation in which this can occur? i.e. the return value from main is changed from non-zero to zero before the process exits?

This is occurring on Windows 7 (x64), with MSVC++ 2010 Express, building a x86 (32-bit) application. I have not seen this odd failure on any of our other Windows or Linux platforms, or compilers, but that doesn't necessarily mean it couldn't happen in those environments.

Comment: Try adding a `catch(...)` to make sure you are catching all the exceptions

Answer (score 1):

If you have any `atexit` handlers that call `exit(0)`, or any static-storage-duration objects whose destructors do that, it might explain what you're seeing. They get executed after your `return` statement. It's undefined behavior, which could explain why you only see it happen sometimes.

Comment: Thanks. This might be it, I will investigate further.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately we don't have any active atexit() functions, which means it's possibly in a static object destructor. I looked at the most obvious ones in our code but they seem to be called fine, even on a run where the return code ends up being 0 (expected to be 2). So it's possible I've missed something somewhere, anyway.

Comment: You can observe this in-house? Use your debugger. Set a breakpoint on `ExitProcess` and see how you get there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not throwing the exception correctly...
I mean that from the function called or processing done in try block, you are throwing exception of some other type.
Try to write a [default catch block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Try-catch_block) for that.

Comment: Definitely throwing & catching the right exception - there's a print in the catch block for exit_request which I can see being printed to stdout. Thanks for the advice anyway.